# sudoedit ignores sticky bit when checking for directory writability

Tags: sudoedit, sticky-bit

sudoedit does not allow editing files when the original user has write access to one of the parent directories (as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356142/sudoedit-root-owned-file-in-a-non-root-directory/356145#356145)). However, I'm noticing that sudoedit does not seem to take into account the sticky bit when performing this check.

For example, I have `/tmp` with mode 1777 owned by root:root, and `/tmp/foo` also owned by root:root. Since `/tmp` has the sticky bit set, I think I should be able to use sudoedit on `/tmp/foo`, but I can't:

```
$ sudoedit /tmp/foo
sudoedit: /tmp/foo: editing files in a writable directory is not permitted
```

Shouldn't sudoedit be able to notice the sticky bit and not consider `/tmp` to be writable for the purposes of this check? Or would doing so introduce some security issue I'm not aware of?